# Installing npm packages to Laravel in 5.7

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I'm trying to install npm packages to my Laravel project. So I've installed npm with `npm install`and then did `npm install masonry-layout` then I ran `npm run watch` and it appears in my node_modules folder.

I've tried adding `require('masonry-layout');` to my app.js and adding `window.anything = require('masonry-layout');` or `window._ = require('masonry-layout');` to my bootstrap.js - im calling it on my view like this:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        isResizable: true,
        transitionDuration: '0.8s',
        isAnimated: true
    });
});
```

My app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('masonry-layout');
require('imagesloaded');
```

bootstrap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.anything = require('masonry-layout');
window.anything = require('imagesloaded');


/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     encrypted: true
// });
```

and yes, I installed imagesLoaded too, but this isnt working either. If I include the cdn to my view it works like it should do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us where you are requiring the `masonry-layout`? Also, are you doing it after you've loaded jQuery?

Comment: I tried both, before and after requiring jQuery. What do you mean by showing where I require masonry-layout? I'm including the app.js in my view file, that should do it I guess? Or do I have to require masonry-layout in my view too? Because then I could just add the cdn, thats not what I want.

Comment: I want to see your js file. You are only showing a part of the code.

Comment: my resources/js/app.js includes just require('masonry-layout');
require('imagesloaded');

Comment: It's not loading the bootstrap file?

Comment: I'm just including my app.js which is located in /public/js/ like <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

Comment: What I mean is, did you remove `require('./bootstrap');` from your `app.js`?

Comment: No, sorry, its in there.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the whole contents of your `app.js` and `bootstrap.js` so I can locate the issue?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading `masonry-layout` and `imagesLoaded` before loading your `jQuery`. You should have it load after jQuery like this:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    window.Masonry = require('masonry-layout');
    window.ImagesLoaded = require('imagesloaded');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
new Masonry('.grid', {
    // options
});
```

Also, you can remove them from your `app.js`.

### Note

If you really want to be able to use it like `$('.grid').masonry(...)`, then you need to install `jquery-bridget`:

```
npm install jquery-bridget
```

Then do this in your bootstrap file:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Masonry = require('masonry-layout');

// make Masonry a jQuery plugin
jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );

// now you can use $().masonry()
$('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 80
});
```

For more information: https://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#webpack

Comment: Now my app.js just includes require('./bootstrap'); and I have done it like you showed but its still not working.

Comment: $grid.masonry is not a function

Comment: Now its working. Finally! Thank you so much. Now when I want to install more packages do I just need to call them inside the try block?

Comment: @Jascusi You can put them anywhere in your boostrap file. But if it needs jQuery, put it in the try block to have jQuery loaded first.